# Flagging profane comments?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

If you see a comment with a "bad" word in it, are you supposed to flag it?

I did that recently, and while the comment was removed, my flag weight surprisingly (?) went down. Are curse words encouraged on the site, or did the lowering of my flag weight the moderator's way of telling me I should've just pretended like I hadn't seen the comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you flagged anything else but that comment recently? Also how much did the weight do down by? If it went down by 5 then it was a comment or if it went down by 10 it is a question or answer.

Comment: Huh, it went down by 10, not 5. Hm... how recently is "recently"? AFAIK, the last thing I flagged was sometime yesterday (or the day before?), and I thought I saw my flag weight go *up* because of that, not down. Maybe I'm wrong, though...

Comment: Well @Mehrdad try to think what you flagged and I might see it/

Comment: @Benny: Wait, what? *You* might see it? Are you a moderator or something?

Comment: @Mehrdad saddly no :(

Comment: Oh never mind, I remembered what it was.

Comment: @Mehrdad - Keep in mind that it's not unusual for us to act on your flags out of the order that they were submitted. It depends on the severity of the flag and how many other flags any given post or comment has received.

Comment: @Tim: Totally forgot that, good point. :)